# Auto play video in webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, html5-video, qwebview

I am new in android and I am displaying a news link in a webview. News link contains a video. Problem is that, After opening a link i have to click on video then video is playing but i want that video should be play automatically.

Thanks in advance.

My code is:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);         

myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) { web.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play(); })()"); }
    });

myWebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
myWebView.loadUrl("http://aajtak.intoday.in/livetv.html");
```

Answer (score 31):

myWebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(boolean)

Note: Only for API level 17 and above.

Comment: I don't know if it makes to enable video auto play in all case but perfect me. Thank you very much.

Comment: This works, but I had to manually specify this in JS too: `document.getElementById("video").muted = "true";` just setting `muted` in HTML didn't work for me. if you just take this code make sure you match the HTML ID of your video.

Answer (score 15):

This works for me.

```
webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

using above, after opening a link no need to click on video, the video is playing automatically.

Answer (score 3):

video on webview didn't support 'autoplay'.
so we shoud start video by hand:
android:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
 super.onPageFinished(view, url);
 view.loadUrl("javascript:onPageFinished();"); 
}
```

JS:

```
function onPageFinished() {
    var video = document.getElementById("video");
    video.play();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {web.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play(); })()"); }
});
```

You should implement `loadUrl` on the WebView...
Simply replace `web.loadUrl` with `view.loadUrl` and it should work just fine

Comment: it gives me an error in console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined", source:

Comment: The error given implies that the JavaScript code `document.getElementsByTagName('video')` is returning an empty list, meaning that your video is not placed inside a `<video></video>` Tag in HTML.

Comment: @AliNoureddine , my video is inside <video> tag but still I am getting that error!

Answer (score 1):

Just make your webview thinking he is running in PC instead mobile
Insert this os MainActivity file

```
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("1");//for desktop 1 or mobile 0.
```

Comment: where's the references?